# Copy selected option to another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I feel there may be an answer to this, if so, I can't find it.

I have a form, a billing and shipping address. I have a checkbox that says "billing is the same as shipping address" When that is checked, I want to copy all values from the billing address section to the shipping address selection. I have been able to copy over the text fine, but the select option for the country seems to be trickier than anticipated. Here's what I have so far:

```
<select class="span12" id="BillingCountry" name="BillingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<select class="span12" id="ShippingCountry" name="ShippingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="duplicate-address" name="duplicate-address" value="shipping same as billing">&nbsp;&nbsp;Shipping address is same as billing</label>

$('#duplicate-address').click(function(e) {
    if( $('#duplicate-address').prop('checked') ){
        $("#ShippingAddress").val($("#BillingAddress").val()); //works
        $("#ShippingCountry").val($("#BillingCountry").val());
    }
});
```

So if I select in the billing country Albania and press the checkbox, I expect to see the shipping country to have Albania selected as well. Any pointers i nthe right direction would be fantastic

Comment: Works fine in this bin: http://jsbin.com/lalukaqusa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: so it does.. Well i'm baffled as I did a direct copy paste.. I must have something else going funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want on checkbox state change select the same option in #ShippingCountry as in #BillingCountry, here the code:

```
<select class="span12" id="BillingCountry" name="BillingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<select class="span12" id="ShippingCountry" name="ShippingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="duplicate-address" name="duplicate-address" value="shipping same as billing">&nbsp;&nbsp;Shipping address is same as billing</label>

$('#duplicate-address').click(function(e) {
    if( $('#duplicate-address').prop('checked') ){
     $('#ShippingCountry').val($('#BillingCountry option:selected').val())
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t1y4ydx6/)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I got right your question. Here it is!

```js
var shipping = jQuery('#ShippingCountry');
var billing = jQuery('#BillingCountry');

billing.on('change', function(e){
    var selected = jQuery('option:selected', this);
    shipping.val(selected.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="span12" id="BillingCountry" name="BillingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<select class="span12" id="ShippingCountry" name="ShippingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
</select>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="duplicate-address" name="duplicate-address" value="shipping same as billing">&nbsp;&nbsp;Shipping address is same as billing</label>
```